# How to add map to map array in AWS DynamoDB only when id is not existed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

Here is my DynamoDB structure.

```
 {"books": [
  {
   "name": "Hello World 1",
   "id": "1234"
  },
  {
   "name": "Hello World 2",
   "id": "5678"
  }
 ]}
```

I want to set `ConditionExpression` to check whether id existed before adding new items to `books` array. Here is my `ConditionExpression`. I am using API gateway to access DynamoDB.

```
"ConditionExpression": "NOT contains(#lu.books.id,:id)",
"ExpressionAttributeValues": {":id": {
        "S": "$input.path('$.id')"
    }
}
```

Result when I test the API: no matter id existed or not, success to add items to array.

Any suggestion on how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: `lu.books.id` was never going to work. Your `lu.books` doesn't have an `id`. It's a list of maps so you'd use array indexing to access the N'th map. However, there is no way afaik to specify "any of the elements in a map".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't. However, there is a workaround.

Store the books in separate rows. For example

```
PK           SK
BOOK_LU#<ID> BOOK_NAME#<book name>#BOOK_ID#<BOOK_ID>
```

Now you can use the 'if_not_exists' conditional expression

```
"ConditionExpression": "if_not_exists(id, :id)'",
"ExpressionAttributeValues": {":id": {
        "S": "$input.path('$.id')"
    }
}
```

The con is if you were previously fetching the list as part of another object you will have to change that.

The pro is that now you can easily work with the books + you won't hit the max row size limits if the books became too many.

Comment: Is using Lambda function also a possible method? Considering the cost, do you know which one will be more effective?

Comment: Is it more cost-effective than a server? For sure, but keep in mind that lambdas are harder to debug. The good thing is that they have native integration with AWS services and require way less setup and configurations